# Advice about my jQuery script + compatibility with iDevices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, toggle

I posted a question about a script but I have another question about another script.

I have two blue buttons at the beginning that turn gray on a roll-over.
Blue becomes (and remains) gray when you click on one of the two buttons.
Both buttons must not be blue both. Each button brings up a form at a time (form contact and form quotation).

- I have wrote this and I would to know if I can simplify it ?
- How to make the "toggle" function compatible with iDevices (iPad, iPhone...) ?

Thank you in advance.

```
$(function() {
    $("#form-contact").hide();
    $("#form-devis").hide();

      $("#btn-contact").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("btn-form-hover");    
        $("#form-contact").fadeToggle(500, "linear");
        $("#form-devis").hide();
        $("#btn-devis").removeClass("btn-form-hover");
  });

    $("#btn-devis").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("btn-form-hover");
        $("#form-devis").fadeToggle(500, "linear");
        $("#form-contact").hide();
        $("#btn-contact").removeClass("btn-form-hover");
  });

});
```

Comment: Could you post your html markup?

Answer (score 0):

This looks about as simple as you can get for forcing only one button to have the "selected" state. If you need to do this for many elements, see my code below.

Toggle should work on iDevices as long as the jQuery library you included supports it. However, you will not get a hover effect on iDevices since there is no mouse.

**Code Example:**

If you plan to do this frequently with buttons (rocker switches) where only one element can have the "selected" state you could make a function like this:

**CodePen**: http://codepen.io/Skrypt/pen/dyCha

**HTML**

```
<div class="rockerSwitch myRocker1">
  <button class="left">On</button><button class="right">Off</button>
</div>
<div class="rockerSwitch myRocker2">
  <button class="left">True</button><button class="right">False</button>
</div>
<div class="rockerSwitch myRocker3">
  <button class="left">Option 1</button><button class="right">Option 2</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rockerSwitch button {
  background-color: #dcffb2;
  border: 1px solid #87cf30;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}
.rockerSwitch button.left {
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
.rockerSwitch button.right {
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
.rockerSwitch button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.rockerSwitch button.selected {
  background-color: #87cf30;
}
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('.myRocker1').rockerSwitch();
  $('.myRocker2').rockerSwitch();
  $('.myRocker3').rockerSwitch();
});

$.fn.rockerSwitch = function() {
  var left = $('.left', this);
  var right = $('.right', this);

  left.on('click', function() {
    left.addClass("selected");
    right.removeClass("selected");
  });
  right.on('click', function() {
    right.addClass("selected");
    left.removeClass("selected");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is what I would like for my buttons, but how to include the fact that a button keep his class when we click on it ?

Comment: It keeps the "selected" class when it is clicked. I'm not sure what else you mean